# Lower bound on the sum of square roots of probabilities that are upper and lower bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $p_i$ with $i=1,\ldots,n$ be probabilities, that is $\sum_i p_i =1$. Moreover each term is bounded according to
$$
\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon \leq p_i \leq \frac{1}{n}+\epsilon
$$
I want to find the minimum in terms of $\epsilon$ of the following function
$$
f(\vec{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}}
$$
Is it true that this occurs when one term is exactly $\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon$, one is  $\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon$ and the rest are just $\frac{1}{n}$? So, in other words can I show that
$$
f(\vec{p}) \geq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(n-2+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon}\right)
$$
One can explicitly show that this is true in the case $n=2$ but I am not sure how/if this generalizes for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \varepsilon} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} - \varepsilon} \leq 2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$. You can repeatedly apply this and show that that $f(p)$ is smaller that what you wrote for the case when half of them are $1/n + \varepsilon$ and the remaining are $1/n - \varepsilon$. I suspect this value will be the smallest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If $n$ is even:**

From the given condition, we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon\right)}\le \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}}\le \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon\right)} \hspace{1cm} \text{for all }1\le  i\le n $$
$$\Longrightarrow  \left(\sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon\right)} \right)  \left(\sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon\right)} \right)\le0 \hspace{1cm} \text{for all }1\le  i\le n $$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{p_i}{n} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon} \right) \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2} \le 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{for all }1\le  i\le n  \tag{1}$$

Make the sum of $(1)$ for all $i\in\{1,..,n \}$, and use the condition $\sum_i^np_i=1$, we deduce
$$\frac{1}{n} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon} \right)\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} }+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2} \le 0$$

$$\iff \color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} \ge \frac{\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon} \right)} }$$

The equality occurs if and only if $p_i = \frac{1}{n}-\epsilon$ or $p_i = \frac{1}{n}+\epsilon$.

**If $n$ is odd :** **still don't know how to do**, I guess we can do as follows:

The first condition is equal to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p_i = 1-p_{n}$$

Apply the same method above, we may deduce that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} =\sqrt{\frac{p_n}{n}}+ \sum_{i=1}^\color{red}{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{p_i}{n}} \ge \sqrt{\frac{p_n}{n}} + \frac{\frac{\color{red}{1-p_n}}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-\epsilon}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon} \right)} $$

Comment: Nice! I think that your inequality in red is true regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even. What changes is that if $n$ is odd, then perhaps the bound is a bit soft and can't be saturated, while if $n$ is even, equality is achieved if half are with the minus and the rest with the plus. I will wait for a bit to see what other have to add and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**For odd** $n$:

**Problem**: Let $n\ge 3$ be a fixed odd number. Let $0 < \epsilon\le \frac{1}{n}$ be fixed. Let $p_i\ge 0, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$
with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$ and
$\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon \le p_i \le \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$. Find the minimum of
$$f(p) := \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{p_i}.$$

**Answer**: The minimum of $f(p)$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}
\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon}
+ \frac{n-1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \epsilon} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$
when $p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{(n-1)/2} = \frac{1}{n} - \epsilon$ and $p_{(n+1)/2} = \frac{1}{n}$
and $p_{(n+1)/2 + 1} = p_{(n+1)/2 + 2} = \cdots = p_n = \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$.

**Proof**:

WLOG, assume that $p_1 \le p_2 \le \cdots \le p_n$.

Note that if $\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon < x \le y < \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$, then there exists $t > 0$
such that $\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon < x - t < y + t < \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$ and
$$\sqrt{x - t} + \sqrt{y + t} < \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}.$$
(*Note*: $\iff 2\sqrt{(x - t)(y+t)} < 2\sqrt{xy} \iff t(t - x + y) > 0$.)
In other words, if there exist $i\ne j$, $p_i, p_j \in (1/n - \epsilon, 1/n + \epsilon)$,
then $(p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n)$ is not optimal.
Thus, at minimum, there exists at most one $p_j \notin \{1/n - \epsilon, 1/n + \epsilon\}$

Thus, at minimum, there exists $k\in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ such that
$$p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_k = \frac{1}{n} - \epsilon$$
and
$$p_{k+2} = p_{k+3} = \cdots = p_n = \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon.$$

From $\sum_{k=1}^n p_i = 1$, we have
$$k(1/n - \epsilon) + (n - k - 1)(1/n + \epsilon) + p_k = 1$$
which results in $p_k = \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon(2k + 1 - n)$.

From $\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon \le p_k \le \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$, we have $n/2 - 1\le k \le n/2$. Since $n$ is odd, we have $k = \frac{n-1}{2}$.
Thus, $p_{(n-1)/2} = \frac{1}{n}$, and $p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{(n-1)/2} = \frac{1}{n} - \epsilon$, and $p_{(n-1)/2+1} = p_{(n-1)/2+2} = \cdots = p_n = \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice  approach! _

Comment: @NN2 Thanks! Your solution is nice as well.

Comment: @RiverLi Nice answer! Thanks for adding it :-)

Comment: @AG1123 You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I am just going to add another approach, even though @NN2 's answer is better. One can use a reverse Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, namely the Pólya–Szegő inequality,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k \right)^2 \geq \frac{1}{C} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2
$$
with
$$
C=\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{\frac{M_1 M_2}{m_1 m_2}} +\sqrt{\frac{m_1 m_2}{M_1 M_2}}\right)^2
$$
and $0<m_1\leq a_i \leq M_1$,$0<m_2\leq b_i \leq M_2$.

Taking $a_i=\sqrt{p_i}$ and $b_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, we find
$$
f(\vec{p})^2 \geq  \frac{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2}}{\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-\epsilon^2}} \,,
$$
which seems to give the same bound as in @NN2's answer. However, the derivation is not elegant as it depends on the knowledge of that particular inequality.

In fact, in the following reference there are more reverse Cauchy-Schwartz-type inequalities but I haven't checked if all bounds coincide in this case.
https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n1/ReverseSchwarz.pdf

**EDIT:**
I made a mistake and even though the bounds are pretty similar when $n << 1/\epsilon$, for $n\sim 1/\epsilon$ my bound is smaller and less tight. I have added a plot where I compare the two for values of $n$ up to 1000 and with $\epsilon=1/1000$. The curve in blue is my bound while in red the one from @NN2's answer.

[image]

Comment: In your link, it seems to me that the method "Generalised Diaz-Metcalf ’s inequality" (page 3) may work. But I don't know whether it works only for $n$ even or for all $n$.